# Find value with associative array without know the key in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with this structure:

```
{"user":{
     "nice":{
         "funny":"sure"
             }
     ,
     "notnice":{
         "funny":"maybe"
             }
     }
}
```

I know the keys "user","funny" and the value "sure" and "maybe" but I don't know "nice" and "notnice".

How do I do an optimized query to search through many documents.

For example, if I want to search "sure" value knowing the middle keys I do:

```
$document = $users->findOne([
'$or' => [
        ['user.nice.funny' => 'sure'],
        ['user.notnice.funny' => 'sure']
    ]
]
```

);

But how do I do the same without knowing "nice" and "notnice".

Comment: Could you please clarify the JSON structure? Where is the array?

Comment: That JSON structure is the associative array it self.

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "userTransformed": {
            $objectToArray: "$user" // transform "user" field into key-value pair
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "userTransformed.v.funny": "sure" // just filter on the values
    }
})
```

Frankly, this is not going to be fast for lots of documents but there is no other way. Indexes will not be used by this query. If you want to get faster you will need to change your document structure.

Comment: I notice the error and updated JSON structure, User field holds associative keys.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Good stuff. Makes the code even easier. ;) See my updated answer.